# Windows 7 file explorer Accessibility issue?

Tags: windows

1. I have an Accessibility problem on Windows 7.
2. I am older and am experiencing vision difficulties in reading the existing font's contrast on the Windows 7, Windows Explorer file explorer program.
3. The existing font in the Windows Explorer file explorer is too narrow and pale for me to easily read it.
4. I have tried enlarging text, but need to change settings that will allow Windows Explorer to display a bolder font within the displayed Windows Explorer window.

Comment: Start menu -> write Magnifier. It will take a little getting used to.

Comment: What settings are you using now? Resolution ? Cleartype enabled? text size DPI ?  What is screen size? I use a 56 " TV on 1080p  Choose a better theme of manually change fonts to 14 with B old , change DPI to 125%

Answer (score 1):

[image]

What settings are you using now? Resolution ? Cleartype enabled? text size DPI ? What is screen size? I use a 56 " TV on 1080p Choose a better theme of manually change fonts to 14 with B old , change DPI to 125%  (150% may not work well with linear zoom in some applications from box constraints)

[image]

**Choose better Fonts and size for each option.**

**If these do not work for you after reboot
I recommend https://winaero.com/**  to change all EXPLORER fonts and sizes which does not include your browser.